# How to use Inet6Address in java

Tags: java, netty

Once again i require some small help on how i can make use of Inet6Address on java.

As i develop a application on getting IPv4 address but now i wanna extend it to IPv6. And it seem that i cant get a IPv6 address and it keep get IPv4 address.

ANd i try to import java.net.Inet6Address;

With the existing code that i have which is show below.

```
public SocketAddress getInetAddress(){
   return channel.getRemote();
}
```

The channel is using the netty project.

How can i do with Inet6Address?

As i found on this web
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html

```
public InetSocketAddress getInetAddress(){
   Inet6Address ipv6 = (Inet6Address)channel.getRemoteAddress.**getAddress();**

    return channel.getRemote();
}
```

Can i also ask if the .getAddress() cant be use, Can anyone help me on this issues?

Like do i need to download a jar file to work on this?

The version of java i am using is java 6.

From Swift

Answer (score 0):

if you are ok - try to use

[Java-ipv6](http://code.google.com/p/java-ipv6/)

Comment: Hi TechExchange,

erm what i am doing is something to get An IPv6 adddress remotely. Using netty.

Can i do that with the link you provide? Can do some example.

From Swift

Answer (score 0):

what is the type of your `channel`?  never used 'netty', but in sun's nio world, assuming `sa` is an instance of `SocketAddress`, just use `sa.getAddress()`. if `sa` is representing a socket on IPv4 address, you will get an instance of `Inet4Address`, or a `Inet6Address` when it is a socket on IPv6 address.

add some IPv6 bind code:

```
InetAddress[] addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName("localhost");
Inet6Address add6 = null;
for(InetAddress add : addresses) { 
    if (add instanceof Inet6Address) {
        add6 = add;
        break;
    }
}
if (add6==null)
    throw new RuntimeException("no IPv6 local address found!");
InetSocketAddress sa=new InetSocketAddress(add6, port);
...
```

Comment: is it `org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel`? maybe we should dig into netty code more deeply...

Comment: Hi notxx Ya it is some way there but it is from org.jboss.netty.channel.Channel <-- there is a method in there call getRemoteAddress();

Comment: getRemoteAddress() return type is SocketAddress.

It is from this website.
http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/Channel.html

Comment: is your application the server side or the client side?

Comment: Server side.
So can i use something do with the Inet6Address?

Comment: i think it's like `InetAddress add = ((InetSocketAddress)channel.getRemoteAddress()).getAddress()` and whether or not add is IPv6 does not matter.

Comment: isn't this is for getting IPv4 Addresses?

Comment: no. in fact `InetAddress` could be `Inet4Address`(IPv4) or `Inet6Address`(IPv6), depending on the underlying connection.

Comment: erm ok ya true also ok.
notxx thank for you help i will go try it out really thank for your help =)

Comment: But can i be more just use Inet6Address add = ((InetSocketAddress)channel.getRemoteAddress()).getAddress()? 

Will i have Problem with this?

Comment: if you are sure the underlying connection is IPv6, just cast `InetAddress` into `Inet6Address`.

Comment: That is the thing lo it seem that i cant just cast Inetaddress into Inet6Address. ANy idea how i can do it?

Comment: `Inet6Address add = (Inet6Address)((InetSocketAddress)channel.getRemoteAddress()).getAddress()`?

Comment: i have an erro on mismatch cannot covert from InetAddress to Inet6Address =(

Comment: i think it is Inet4Address, that suggests, the underlying connection is using IPv4 address. r u sure the connections is using IPv6?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

Ya that i what i think also. That why i couldn't get my IPv6 Address.

Erm of the connections wise i using both IPv4 and IPv6 connection Starting i thought it will give me both the IPv4 and IPv6 address.

Then it end up on giving me only IPv4 address =(

Can guide me Notxx do i need to edit netty project to do that??

Comment: have not use netty yet. maybe you could just bind your service to your IPv6 local address, then no IPv4 connection will take place.

Comment: how can i can i do it any idea?

Comment: in your code, you must bind the server port somewhere. specify IPv6 address and port to bind there. then connect to that address and port.

Comment: erm is there a sample on how to do it?

Comment: i mean, no matter where you bind the server port, change the code there. change it into IPv6 only, use `Inet6Address` to construct a `InetSocketAddress` and specify the `InetSocketAddress` to the bind method.

Comment: Hi notxx,
The way how i did it is 
InetSockAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress(Openport);
Final ChannelGroup cg = new DefaultChannelGrop();
cg.add(bootstrap.bind(sa));

THis is how i did it...

Comment: oh, you just specified port. try the code just added in the answer.